# Using a markov chain to calculate the expected value of conditional/constrained choices (TopCoder PancakeStack)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I've been working on a programming challenge ([link](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13747)) where an expected value is calculated.

Recently I learned about Markov chains and successfully applied them to solving a set of problems, but the problems did not involve constraints as in this one.

Because I'm quite new to the field, can anyone give me hints about terminology I should search, or how to set up the problem to solve it via markov chain application? Is this problem something where Markov chains are applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not suited to Markov chains, IMO. It is more suited to combinatorial probability (i.e. counting the ways that specified outcomes (events) can happen).

For $i=0,1,\ldots,N-1$, define:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Event: }\quad S_i &=& \text{Pancake $i$ is on the stack} \\
&& \\
\text{R.V.: }\quad X\; &=& \text{Total deliciousness of the stack} \\
\text{R.V.: }\quad X_i &=& \text{Total deliciousness of the stack due to Pancake $i$.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

So we have $X = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}X_i$. Note that $X_i=0$ if Pancake $i$ is not on the stack. So we require:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X) &=& E\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} X_i\right) \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} E(X_i) \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} d_i P(S_i) \qquad\qquad\text{where $d_i$ is the deliciousness of Pancake $i$.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Probability $P(S_i)$ depends on when Pancake $i$ was selected. If it was the $j^{th}$ one selected, then for it to go on the stack all previous $j-1$ selections must be larger (i.e. Pancakes $i+1$ to $N-1$) and must have been selected in descending order. There are $\binom{N-i-1}{j-1}$ ways to pick $j-1$ from those $N-i-1$ pancakes (in the required descending order). The total number of permutations of $j-1$ pancakes, given that the $j^{th}$ one is Pancake $i$ and is therefore excluded, is $(N-1)!/(N-j)!$ since we have $N-1$ to choose from. Thus,

$$P(S_i\mid \text{Pancake $i$ is the $j^{th}$ selection}) = \binom{N-i-1}{j-1} \bigg/ \dfrac{(N-1)!}{(N-j)!}.$$

So we continue, using the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X) &=& \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} d_i \sum_{j=1}^{N}P(S_i\mid \text{Pancake $i$ is $j^{th}$ selection})P(\text{Pancake $i$ is the $j^{th}$ selection}) \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} d_i \sum_{j=1}^{N-i} \dfrac{1}{N} \binom{N-i-1}{j-1} \bigg/ \dfrac{(N-1)!}{(N-j)!} \\
&& \qquad\qquad\text{Upper limit for $j$ is $N-i$: for higher $j$, event $S_i$ is impossible} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} d_i \sum_{j=1}^{N-i} \dfrac{(N-j)!}{N!} \binom{N-i-1}{j-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I followed along until the 2nd-to-last line where a factor of $\frac 1 N$ snuck in somehow. Where did that come from?

Comment: Hi @Shamster , That is $P(\text{Pancake $i$ is the $j^{th}$ selection})$. Since all $N$ pancakes are equally likely to be the $j^{th}$ selection, that probability is $1/N$ for all $j$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. One more: there is the constraint that every pancake chosen before the $j^{th}$ is larger than it, and also chosen in a descending order. I'm still not quite understanding how the descending order constraint is upheld here.

Comment: By the time we've made the $j^{th}$ selection, wouldn't we have fewer than N pancakes from which to choose?

Comment: @Shamster Descending order question: The descending order is achieved by using the binomial coefficient $\binom{N-i-1}{j-1}$ as the count and NOT multiplying it by the number of ways you could re-arrange the selection. For the TOTAL number of ways, we DO multiply the binomial coefficient by the #ways to arrange the selected $j-1$ pancakes (which is $(j-1)!$ ways). i.e. $(N-1)!/(N-j)!=\binom{N-1}{j-1}(j-1)!$ E.g. If $N=6,i=1,j=3$ to get the $i^{th}$ pancake on the stack, the selection of the previous $j-1=2$ pancakes must be one of: $54,53,52,43,42,32$, which are the $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

Comment: @Shamster $j^{th}$ selection question: For the value $P(\text{Pancake $i$ is the $j^{th}$ selection})$ think like this: the $i^{th}$ pancake must be selection number $1$ or $2$ or ... or $N$. Without knowing anything else, it is equally likely to be any of those numbers. What you are talking about is a probability something like $P(\text{Pancake $i$ is the $j^{th}$ selection $\mid$ Pancake $i$ is not in the fist $j-1$ selections})$.